# IBOutlet in ScrollView producing nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, iboutlet

I have a simple UILabel, nothing special about it, in a UIView inside a UIScrollView. I can link it up to my ViewController.swift file just fine, and it doesn't crash on opening, but whenever I try to use the outlet, it produces a nil. I've been looking around for a solution and it seems as though you can't access an outlet inside a subview from the superview... but nothing has been exactly my situation, and none of the provided solutions work.

Here is the full error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

The strange thing, though, is that I have another UILabel, seemingly the exact same, that works fine when I try to edit it. I do not know what is going on in the slightest here. How can I fix this?

Comment: try to remove and connect the outlet again

Comment: In what function are you using the label? in your `init` or in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: It's in a function I created that gets called a few seconds after the view initializes

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar I've already tried that twice to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

"right click" no your label in storyboard and check if you don't have another outlet connected, maybe you deleted from code and connection is still there, other than that, you can delete the label from storyboard and recreate connections.

Comment: There is only one connection when I right click it, and I've already tried re-connecting it twice

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the @IBOutlet as not weak and try.

This is not the right way, but still let us see if it's working.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect